# How to compare two array of strings and get the string values in jquery?

Tags: jquery, string

I am working in jQuery and I need to compare two arrays of strings which are as follows:

```
var A = ['dada','adad','a','s','rrrrrrrr'];

var B = ['dada','adad','a','s'];
C = [];
```

I need to compare those two arrays of strings and I need to get the difference, i.e the 'rrrrrrr' value after the compare.

```
$.each(A, function (i, e) {
     if ($.inArray(e, B) == -1) C.push(e);
); 
alert(C);
```

My output is:

```
C= r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r
```

However, I expected this output:

```
C=rrrrrrrrrr
```

Comment: Your code works for me.

Comment: If you aren't opposed to another library, underscore.js can make this a one liner with the `_.difference` function. http://underscorejs.org

Comment: You probably do something else we don't see that changes "rrr..." to an array of letters (like slicing).

Comment: What a mess. Please take better care over your questions.

Comment: actually i am getting A array dynamically comparing with b when compare i need to get the values which is not containing in B array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function exclusive(a,b){
    var c = [];

    $.each(a, function(){
        var self = this.toString();

        if(b.indexOf(self) === -1){
            c.push(self);
        }
    });

    return c;
}
```

Example:

```
var A = ['dada','adad','a','s','rrrrrrrr'];

var B = ['dada','adad','a','s'];

exclusive(A,B)
```

> ["rrrrrrrr"]

Comment: no it dosen't work getting this out put [object Window],[object Window],[object Window],[object Window],[object Window],[object Window],[object Window],[object Window],[object Window],[object Window],[object Window],[object Window],[object Window],[object Window],[object Window],[object Window],[object Window],[object Window],[object Window],[object Window],[object Window],[object Window],[object Window]

Comment: sorry, scoping issues. try the edited version. I tested it in my console.

Comment: yes it's working fine but how could i get the c value i need to add to out of the function how to get form that function

Comment: `var C = exclusive(A,B);` ?

Comment: @bevacqua I am trying to search strings from an array in another string (of words) using this solution. In my case I have an array `a = [bat, cat, rat]`. I am trying to locate if **cat** is missing from string `b = 'bat is not a cat'`. However, I am getting result: `bat,cat,rat`. **How do I check** for the presence (or absence) of a word from a sting?